# Handle reucrring events in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to rails and currently deal with recurring events. I have a function that a user can select the recurring events such as 'Monday','Tuesday' and what I was going to do is, create columns for each of the days with the boolean type and it will be set as `false` and update to `true` if there is any input but I feel like this is not a really efficient way. I looked up some `gem` such as ice-cube. However, that seems too much for me, like all I need is storing the recurring events if a user adds and display the user based on the day. For example, if it is Monday, show the users who is added to `Monday`. Is there any recommendation or better way to achieve that other than using gem?

Answer (score 0):

Ice Cube does sound like overkill since you're just looking to run code on a specific day of the week. Luckily, Ruby has a 'date' class that can do what you want.

In your model calls, require `'date'`, get the current date and run the day of week methods against that current date.

```
2.4.0 :008 > require 'date'
 => true 
2.4.0 :009 > foo = Date.today
 => #<Date: 2018-09-09 ((2458371j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.4.0 :010 > foo.monday?
 => false 
2.4.0 :011 > foo.sunday?
 => true 
2.4.0 :012 > foo.friday?
 => false
```

If using `.sunday?`, `.monday?` etc. doesn't work for you, you can get the day of the week like this:

```
day_of_week = foo.wday  # 0 = Sun, 1 = Mon etc.
```

This way, you could have a method that accepts `user_id` and `day_of_week` arguments which you can use to check whether your backend indicates some action for this user on this day of the week.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! very appreciate it.  so you are recommending to have columns in the table like how I planned. Right?

Comment: @Jay Exactly. The goal whenever possible is to supply an answer that suits your conditions as opposed to forcing you to change your plans. To that end, I've only included details on how to determine day of the week, while remaining purposely vague on the specific implementation.